# PowerPC executable doesn't show debugging symbols in Ghidra

Tags: ghidra, debugging-symbols

I have a PowerPC executable (Wipeout 2097 for Macintosh) that when opened in IDA will have all its function names resolved from debugging symbols in the executable right out of the box.

In Ghidra however, it doesn't happen.

Do you know if there is anything particular to do in Ghidra to fetch function names from debugging symbols ?